# How to fetch data from my google analytics account to use on site?

Tags: javascript, python, google-api, google-analytics-api

Consider that I am owner of http://ethernalsite.com

On my website i've added google analytics script and it's happily collecting data about my precious visitors.
I would like to create page views counter. How I can fetch data from **my own** account?
I mean, from site's account on which data is collected.

I've tried this:

1. create *browser token* on google's developer console and allow access for `ethernalsite.com/*`
   I've got something like: xxxxSyCl5wAzQVSxxxxxKHFcxn6Uxzi-skoFZgo
2. make ajax get on client(javascript) side: [https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A00263622&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&start-date=2014-08-19&end-date=2014-09-02&max-results=50&key=](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A00263622&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&start-date=2014-08-19&end-date=2014-09-02&max-results=50&key=_){KEY}

I've got the following response for ajax get query(firebug)

```
"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data
/ga?ids=ga%3A00263622&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&start-date=2014-08-19&
end-date=2024-09-02&max-results=50&key=xxxxSyCl5wAzQVSxxxxxKHFcxn6Uxzi-skoFZgo"
```

With content:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required",
"message":"LoginRequired","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],
"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
```

In the future I would like to cache this value in the server side and allow client to fetch this data from my server every minute. If you also have tips about solving this problem using python i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Developer Console will only give you the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET. With these keys you will be able to generate an ACCESS_TOKEN and you will have to change your query string to

```
?ids=ga%3A00263622&metrics=ga%3AuniquePageviews&start-date=2014-08-19&end-date=2024-09-02&max-results=50&access_key=xxxxACCESS_KEYxxxx&_src=explorer
```